# finer control of sequence in ioslides

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

Suppose I have a two-column layout with a bulleted list in the left column and an image in the right column (example below); I want the list points to appear incrementally and the image to appear **after the list**.  [This rmarkdown issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/253) suggests that one can make individual bullet points incremental, but the example below doesn't have the desired behaviour.

Pandoc suggests that [one use ". . ." to insert a generic 'pause' in a slide show](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#inserting-pauses), but I haven't been able to make this work in my example. That may be because Pandoc natively supports these formats: "S5, DZSlides, Slidy, Slideous, or reveal.js" (i.e. not including `ioslides`).

I am generally happy with `ioslides` and am not eager to invest in learning yet another slide markup system, but I guess I could switch to [xaringan](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/incremental.html) if the consensus is that there's no way to do what I want in `ioslides` ... (**edit**: based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408057/incremental-slides-do-not-work-with-a-two-column-layout) it is possible, but not very easy, to use incremental bullets in conjunction with a two-column layout in xaringan ...)

I'd be happy with a CSS hack that would let me use some kind of `<div class="pause-after"> ... </div>` construction (the only CSS 'pause' stuff I've been able to find seems to be irrelevant/to be about speech/audio files).

---

Build an HTML from this example by cutting & pasting to a file and `rmarkdown::render("test.rmd")`:

---

```
---
title: "incremental test"
output:
  ioslides_presentation
---

## why use MMA? {.columns-2}

> - avoid omitting potentially important predictors
> - avoid overfitting
> - $\approx$ optimize bias-variance tradeoff
> - avoid stepwise approaches & pairwise comparisons
> - MMA is a **shrinkage estimator**

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/The_Three_Bears_-_Project_Gutenberg_eText_17034.jpg" width="300px">

<font size="4px">Rackham 1837</font>
```

Comment: it looks like the combination of `.build` in the slide options and the `> -` syntax in the bulleted list might do what I want; I'll come back and answer this if no one else has contributed in a day or two

Comment: Have the exact same question; wondering if you managed to find any workaround.